# Seemingly Random Wrong Store View in Email

Tags: email, debug, localisation, ee-1.10

In a client's website, the sales emails is seemingly randomly (so far we've notice it for the order_new and the shipment_new) sent in another language that the language set for the store view the order was placed in.

I have put some logs in the email sending process to try to see at which point the storeId is changed, but so far the issue hasn't arise (or it did but my log don't reveal it).

What could, in your opinion, provoke Magento to use another storeId than the one store in the db?

Edit: Magento version `1.10.0.1`,  no email related custom development or 3rd party modules

Comment: Magento version? Any custom email extensions?

Comment: @Ivan Chepurnyi I've added the info you asked for

Comment: Is there a chance you're running a mobile version of the site and that these orders going through are coming from mobile devices? Is it possible you match the IP address in the orders with user agents in the log_ tables or Apache / Nginx logs?

Comment: No, there's no mobile version, neither any kind of geoip script. Glad you like it, it's nice to know some people out there are using it :-)

Comment: Are you sending the emails directly from the backend by viewing the order and clicking "Send Email"?

Comment: @pspahn not sistematicaly: some of the emails are sent through a cron process that parse some xml files. but it still uses the `Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($savedQtys)->sendEmail(true)`

Comment: I'm guessing that the email is not being sent with a store view set. If I remember correctly, you will need to grab the order's store ID and use this to set the store ID prior to sending the email.

Comment: Did you found an answer? Please share it with us.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt nope, no answer. As it happens randomly it is very difficult to track it. If I ever find the bug I will most certainly share it with you here.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/pull/258

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue that was patched in EE 1.13:

> The locale used to send a new order confirmation e-mail now first
>   checks to see if the customer's locale is the same as the store's
>   locale before attempting to localize the e-mail.

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-later-release-notes

Comment: thanks man, I don't work on this project anymore but I passed the info to the guys in charge now. I don't think they will consider upgrade to 1.13, but maybe they'll try to patch it

Comment: Contact Magento and see if you can get just this patch.

Answer (score 1):

In the Magento Admin under system--> Configuration have you set the correct email settings for the different Configuration Scope?

[image: Scope Configuration]

Comment: Yes, all store views are correctly configured